# Apache POI PPT SLide Page setup option

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, hslf

I am wondering if by any mean, i can set the 'Slide sized for ' as On-ScreenShow (16:9). i mean is there any method in master object in apache poi hslf? I couldn't find it. I have added the image for the reference.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can only have one [page size per file](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-powerpoint/how-can-i-insert-an-a3-sheet-in-an-a4-powerpoint/96350f17-a144-4b69-915e-a007d0492a3f).

To set the page dimension call [SlideShow.setPageSize()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/sl/usermodel/SlideShow.html#setPageSize(java.awt.Dimension)).

To find out which page dimensions 4:3, 16:9 or any other formats are, just create a PPT manually via Powerpoint and check its dimension - or use a [Cross-multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.SlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.SlideShowFactory;

public class SlideSizes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String files[] = { "dim_4_3.ppt", "dim_16_9.ppt" };
        for (String f : files) {
            SlideShow<?,?> ppt = SlideShowFactory.create(new File(f));
            System.out.println(ppt.getPageSize());
        }
    }
}
```